# Removing Branches from GitHub

Tags: git, svn, github

About 3 weeks ago I deleted some branches from my local repository, but never deleted them from my repository on GitHub. I need to clean up some of these branches, but have been unsuccessful.

As an example, I deleted this branch from my local 3 weeks ago: `1234e-proj`

Now I am trying to run:

```
git push origin :1234e-proj
```

and I get this error:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: 1234e-proj
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? This is happening with several branches I have deleted on my local already.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use

```
git push --delete origin '1234e-proj'
```

or

```
git push --mirror origin # warning: pushes all refs and deletes all others!
```

Otherwise, it *should* work. Perhaps you can share the output of a

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: here is some of the output:
git push --delete origin '1234e-proj'
  remotes/origin/5370-event-module
  remotes/origin/5370-revision
  remotes/origin/5370-routes
  remotes/lv/5239h-ftaf
  remotes/lv/5334-ftaf-holiday
  remotes/lv/5334b-ftaf-holiday

I was using 1234e-proj as an example, but i get the same error when trying to delete these branches from the repo. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a wild guess: are those branches actually still in the GitHub repo, visible on the web, or are you just seeing them as remote branches in your repo? (Run `git remote update --prune` to update things; that'll prune them if they're in your local repo only.)

Use `git ls-remote origin` to print the refs on the remote, as the remote sees them, e.g.:

```
406da7803217998ff6bf5dc69c55b1613556c2f4    HEAD
1e501a7c47ad5ada53d3b1acfb9f131f76e969ec    refs/heads/maint
406da7803217998ff6bf5dc69c55b1613556c2f4    refs/heads/master
56e79320f3d9b044c380dfebf136584aaa17ac5b    refs/heads/next
...
```

Find the ones you want to delete, then use `git push :<ref>` to delete, e.g. `git push :refs/heads/branch-foo`.

I'm not entirely sure what's going on for you, but assuming the refs really do exist on the remote, this should be a foolproof way to see and delete them. My best guess is that the refs that you're seeing on GitHub aren't actually in `refs/heads`, so using the unqualified refname doesn't work. (I'm not sure how you'd have ended up in that situation, though!